# Does let variable: typeof import('large-module'); import the full module into memory?

Tags: typescript

For the following snippet:

```
let variable: typeof import('large-module');

async function expensiveOperation () {
  variable = await import('large-module');
  // ...do stuff
}
```

is the 'large-module' loaded into memory before the function is invoked ?
(since the import is written in the type definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not. Typescript will statically resolve the typing. You can see it in the compiled javascript:

```js
let variable;
async function expensiveOperation() {
    variable = await import('large-module');
}
```

Comment: what does statically mean here? what if module contains type definitions?

Comment: @ABOS It's "statically", not "statistically". Typescript can introspect installed modules at compile time to extract typings without actually having to run the module or load the module into scope at runtime.

Comment: yes, I think the term statically is a bit misleading here. TS just goes through file by file, line by file, regardless it is eagerly or lazily loaded module to infer typings.